# Set the next threshold in the array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a little dilemma. I'm trying to make a function that will set my next threshold in an array.
This is a method that divides a number into several parts and adds them to a list and eventually the sum of the elements in the list is equal to the number divided,

```
    private List<int> GetThresholds(int value, int threshold)
{
    List<int> ThresholdList = new List<int>();
    int current = value;
    int decayValue = current / threshold;
    ThresholdList.Add(current);
    for (int i = 0; i < threshold; i++)
    {
        int x = current - decayValue;
        current = x;
        ThresholdList.Add(current);
    }
    return ThresholdList;
}

 private void Awake()
{
    initialValue = GetCount();
    BarriersList = GetThresholds((int)initialValue, animations.Length / 2);
}
```

Now in Update I have a variable that decreases in runtime.

```
 private void Update()
{
    currentValue = GetCount();
    nexDownThresholdValue = GetNextDownThreshold();
}

private float GetCount()
{
    float a = 0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < AllBars.Length; i++)
        a += AllBars[i].precentage;
    return a;
}
```

To better understand what I want I give you an example:

x = 416

y = 4 (the number in how many parts will be divided x)

z = (x/y) = 104;

1 : 416 - 104 = 312

2: 312- 104 = 208

3: 208-104 = 104

4:104-104 = 0

Now if the **currentValue** is less than 416 but greater than 312, then the **nexDownThresholdValue**  is 312...and so on. If I did not explain properly or if the condition is not understood please correct me. thank you

Solution:

```
    private float GetNextDownThreshold()
{
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < BarriersList.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (currentValue > BarriersList[i+ 1])
        {
            n = BarriersList[i +1];
            break;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: I solved :) I wrote the code above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to recommend some code changes:

```
private List<int> GetThresholds(int value, int threshold)
{
    List<int> thresholdList = new List<int>();
    int decayValue = current / threshold;
    for (int i = 1; i <= threshold; i++)
    {
        thresholdList.Add(value - (decayValue * i));
    }
    return thresholdList;
}
```

And as you have sorted array you can just use LINQ

```
private float GetNextDownThreshold()
{
    return BarriersList.First(x => currentValue > x)
}
```

Comment: yes ... you're right ... it's much more readable. Thanks a lot.